# How does firebase realtime database handle multiple requests (security)

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Lets say these are two nodes in the real time database:

```
node_1
|
|-------id_1

        -name:....

|-------id_2

        -name:....

|-------id_3

        -name:....



node_2
|
|-------id_1

        -name:....

|-------id_2

        -name:....

|-------id_3

        -name:....
```

If multiple users at the same time did an `updateChildren()` atomic write at `node_1` and `node_2` , then how are these calls handled:

1. In parallel (all at the same time are handled)?
2. Or like a queue (One after the other)?

ex) user 1 write is handled, then user 2, then user 3 , ...............

I want to understand this to know how to secure nodes.

Thanks.

Comment: After reading through [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database) and determining that Real-time Database updates data synchronously I would say that it deals with updates like a queue. I can attest to this because when deleting or uploading large amounts of data from the database in the past, it would add documents iteratively 1 by 1.

Comment: What do you mean by "atomic write"?  Are you actually referring to an update that simply specifies multiple locations, or a transaction?  It would be helpful if you *edit the question to show your code* so we can be certain what you are doing.

Comment: @DougStevenson I meant by `atomic write` and update to multiple location, but I want to know how firebase handles multiple requests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Non-transactional writes are processed in the order they are received.  The last one to execute will overwrite anything else that might have happened before it at the same location.  The fact that you're doing a multi-location update does not change this behavior.

If you are concerned about clients overwriting each other, then you will either need to use a [transaction](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#save_data_as_transactions) at a single location at a time so that each client can see the current state of the data being written, or you can ensure that they are each writing to different locations (e.g. with a "push" operation that generates an new location).